# Iptables limit time per connecction

Tags: limit, iptables

I would like to prevent hanging connections to out SMTP server by limiting the time of each connection to 10 minutes. Which means that after 10 minutes the connection should be dropped.

Is it possbile with iptables?

Answer (score 0):

If your smtp port is default(25) do this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 10/minute -j DROP
```